# How to configure Azure AD SSO SAML in Nextjs using NextAuth

Tags: next.js, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, next-auth

I am looking for a way to implement Azure AD SSO using saml 2.0 using NextAuth.

I have checked NextAuth provider list and I can find Azure AD is provided but it is only for open connect ID, not for SAML.

I also checked BoxyHQSAML and I found out that they are asking for these.

```
issuer,
clientId,
clientSecret,
```

But my azure admin only provided these urls.

```
Login URL - https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111/saml2
Microsoft Entra Identifier - https://sts.windows.net/1111111/
Logout URL - https://login.microsoftonline.com/111111/saml2
```

How can I implement this SSO?

I have try this package as well, https://samlify.js.org/#/ .

But without metadata file, I cannot implement. Beside, since I am using nextAuth, I would like to stick with it rather than installing new pacakge.